# Deriving instance for data types with functions

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a data type representing an objects position that can 'GO', 'STOP', move 'FORWARD', and move 'BACKWARD'. I can't figure out how to write the deriving instance of 'Eq' and 'Show' for the functions FORWARD and BACKWARD.

```
data Moves = GO
           | STOP
           | FORWARD { f :: Int -> Int -> Int }
           | BACKWARD { g :: Int -> Int -> Int }
           deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (Eq Moves) where
    FORWARD a == FORWARD b = True
    FORWARD a == BACKWARD b = True
    BACKWARD a == BACKWARD b = True
    BACKWARD a == FORWARD b = True
    _ == _ = False
```

The logic for the instance doesn't matter at the moment I just can't figure out how to get it to compile. Thanks

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm not quite sure how i should write the syntax for it though, I can't get the instance to compile, as currently i'm trying to make everything just evaluate to `True` regardless of input

Comment: What was the compile error?

Comment: @w13rfed apologies, I deleted my comment because on reflection I think I misunderstood your question. I thought the issue was the lack of an `Eq` instance for functions - this may still cause you problems, but doesn't directly effect any of the code you've got there. As @Ry says, we need the full code (not `...`) and the compiler error(s).

Comment: No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int -> Int)) arising from the first field of 'FOWARD' (type 'Int -> Int -> Int') (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?) Possible fix: use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration, so you can specify the instance context yourself

Comment: Try removing `Eq` from the `deriving`, because you’re implementing it yourself. That’ll lead to better errors.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. Also removing `Eq` from `deriving` gives the same errors but for show and i'm not what the syntax is for data type functions

Comment: Your `Eq` instance is fine, it's the `Eq` in the `deriving` clause that was causing the error. Unfortunately `Show` has the same problem, there is no sensible way to display an arbitrary function in the form of a string so the Haskell Prelude doesn't try to implement `Show` for functions.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks that solved it, could you put it as the proper answer?

Comment: What solved it? You mean removing the `Show` from the `deriving`? OK, but I assumed you wanted an instance, so I'm not sure how this solves your real problem, even if it makes the compiler errors go away.

Comment: The problem was that I thought my syntax was incorrect for the instance, but it was just the deriving part

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. As requested, I have made this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you automatically derive various standard typeclasses via the `deriving` clause, this relies on the individual fields or branches of the data structure already having instances for those classes. Since functions have no default instance for either `Eq` or `Show` (which is perfectly reasonable, there's no obvious canonical way to either determine if 2 arbitrary functions are equal*, or to print them as strings), and your datatype includes 2 fields whose values are functions, it's impossible for Haskell to derive `Eq` and `Show` instances, and this is what the compilation error is about.

The solution is simply to remove the `deriving (Eq, Show)` part - you don't need this anyway if you're going to define your own custom instances. (The only reason to put a `deriving` clause is if you need an instance and are happy with the "standard" one - which a lot of the time you would be. Here though, you seem to be wanting to implement your own instances with non-standard logic. That is fine if your use-case demands it.)

*actually in mathematics it's clear what equality of functions means, functions are defined  by their graph, which means that for two functions to be equal, they must give the same output for every possible input value. That's still theoretically important in Haskell programming (since the "laws" for various type classes require various functions to be equal), but it's not possible to implement in any reasonable way in general, not least because some functions can run forever without giving a result, so actually computing equality of functions in general is rather stronger than solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)!)